# custom data model - link and populate from admin backend

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, database

I read this question [Should I use custom post types or a custom database tables for plugin development?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/47915/77764) and the associated accepted answer, both of which I found very helpful.

My question is, given I am doing some complex functions that require models and queries that don't fit neatly into the WP conception of posts, post_meta, and taxonomies, how do I link these data models and populate them from the admin backend?

I know that I need my own logic for storing and sanitizing into the database as a consequence of my wanting to avoid posts, and I'm fine with that, but I'm asking how would I link them as one of the icons/options in the backend, where posts, pages, and other things are?

Do I have to make a `register_post_type()` and then intercept it? Or is there an option if I make my own data model to somehow embed it and a template/metaboxes as you would do with a custom post in the admin backend?

Comment: WordPress will give you very little help with this, in terms of APIs. `$wpdb` will give you a slightly better way to interact with the database, and `WP_List_Table` might help with some basic UI, but pretty much everything else you'll need to do yourself. Just in terms of adding somewhere in the admin to start, `add_menu_page()` can be used to add a page to the the admin sidebar.

Comment: @JacobPeattie thank you! `add_menu_page()` and the associated callback is what I was looking for I think :) Thanks so much!